# Eye-fi card need key that I believe is a MD5 hash

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, photo, cryptographic-hash-function

I am stuck with some Eyefi cards, because manufacturer decide to disable it by stopping registration server.
I need an Uploadkey for each card in order to use them.  I can get the MAC address of the card, and I believe the hash are generated using these address (may be only right side of the address) plus a salt.  Here are some correct uploadkey and Mac addesses, can anybody help me to find out how can we generate the uploadkey using the MAC address.

```
00-18-56-26-fb-9a f7714f1c6375e329c49704cc2b228610 

00-18-56-27-04-91 3599db80740e842be3e51b1a68c50800 

00-18-56-60-35-32 c6172ad74fd9f3d089114190e7415bf6 

00-18-56-23-89-08 24976afddd2bd6c9ba84024e122313f1 

00-18-56-65-48-89 b884d91ed551e9debcaa30cbbed454cf 

00-18-56-41-cd-45 7d0c4807cdfb93759b38e468fb6f7796 

00-18-56-2b-90-f9 7c207b004d7776b266d7896a42323a81 

00-18-56-65-44-28 d721236649997f7d326c3b00fb3c6f2f 

00-18-56-65-44-3b 48c8cb73afdf13ada7f636ac618ed1c6 

00-18-56-66-a8-71 7989ad884bfd0456f65b5c56655e56a2 

00-18-56-66-a8-ac ba01f5c3a49c5309c7655d3bf8b9dc22 

00-18-56-66-ac-ca 8ee95d7e6f703fd1bc850e057f471973 

00-18-56-66-ac-ac 816c40bdb86a88a79c72a88cc95ed251 

00-18-56-66-a0-f9 1cfa78d59161a0ef2068a33cf29a83a9 

00-18-56-65-48-c8 f26d16bb221bfb2953cdfc65cc0491a3 

00-18-56-66-a1-ee 4e1803543ac47884ebb1437a966f89e2 

00-18-56-66-a2-22 386b8a3c6a37828df4b6fccbe8ace943 

00-18-56-66-a8-b2 0eae0b55245f2698f28ac496c3c3dbaa 

00-18-56-66-ac-9e f36a098fe506be172fb6b067ef00352d 

00-18-56-65-51-e7 29c555c9c4b413ea539f51f3a82f263e 

00-18-56-48-9a-cd c448958ec576198fdb478febca71c53e 

00-18-56-65-48-ef b07cfd70d1890749ff877e44644e5971 

00-18-56-26-fe-24 9f73c96e263b14a608802317004c6b98 

00-18-56-49-90-6a 364624a58431a5bd65fec56e10003559 

00-18-56-60-86-e0 b831e3985a08d4ae1b17548e35036843 

00-18-56-64-be-d1 9d5de14ff7d31ecc62b17e0adc3d58fa 

00-18-56-64-b7-ac 9fa650cff40dfde43fbf5cac83d8cd8b 

00-18-56-66-ab-01 b7f6f3d1280a0e9fe4ecb839a1c5d452 

00-18-56-64-b8-43 69e5395dc84e529f50dbb61fbea19868 

00-18-56-67-89-c1 f78b834bf125bd1011eea973737655d6 

00-18-56-67-89-b2 636a94f10b111f3ecb2d86e483d3d188 

00-18-56-67-88-f1 cffa4cf562dffae5bff6033bb431b2f7 

00-18-56-67-89-8b 325878ed10fba08597b303913d0ad452 

00-18-56-67-89-95 212a84620afa9468c0ad738256c70087 

00-18-56-67-8b-94 a43af4eadb8dd895ec9218459edb2ced 

00-18-56-67-89-2e e58890a80900371d1b354492885ddefb 

00-18-56-67-89-70 b21c36f15331ec798fc91be09df99fe7 

00-18-56-67-89-b8 fbf58645bf029b265732df898b7fa5a6 

00-18-56-67-89-bd 069a55499764fdae6ff0594938e8e67b 

00-18-56-67-89-3f 5923768b6296380369737e26e41f8a56 

00-18-56-67-89-b5 c8e06cca653a899c58b936c5b67c4f6a 

00-18-56-67-89-52 aac3ab4f10bbb2532e01f58cabce2099 

00-18-56-67-89-20 62c6f2d4366fca2b0bbec0d89f2609c1 

00-18-56-67-89-5b 78480c27f40b440b261e6539b9722ac0 

00-18-56-67-8c-18 393f524169417b63f3d2bd78a4ffe1a8 

00-18-56-27-04-69 5310953393797ce8c51939cd73916ebb 

00-18-56-2b-90-f9 7c207b004d7776b266d7896a42323a81 

00-18-56-2a-8e-c9 8413138729754199101c695391a22129 

00-18-56-41-5f-1d 2d1c710c6c7b7dfd4d4ed151d9b25d60 

00-18-56-67-89-33 d4258a40554dbd14c206e581ed18af5c 

00-18-56-66-aa-90 ce5feb6b1721d1d561daa470fcf516cd 

00-18-56-26-97-49 0a7f3af18d21a39c9a40d1afc9685172 

00-18-56-2b-fa-41 374583671b464330650ca006882b6320 

00-18-56-67-89-95 212a84620afa9468c0ad738256c70087 

00-18-56-2c-14-29 7c0ca21f1e0cf05a21185deecbd8a1ba
```

There are many of us needed this key in order to use the card we paid for...
Referencnce  https://www.os3.nl/_media/2013-2014/courses/ot/connor_stavros.pdf

Comment: I think your best option is to approach the manufacturer directly and ask them to help (or refund whatever you paid for these cards). A letter from a solicitor/attorney might prompt them into action. Brute-forcing the keys is probably going to be very hard, although there are tools like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) that might make things a bit easier. Having said that, I'm going to have to close-vote because this not a programming question. Good luck.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not a programming question

Comment: There are programmers can offer advice on how I can approach this.  Manufacturer is trying to make us paid another 80% of the cost to buy another new card...